# Embedded entity "with Text" reading from originaly stored as Blob

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

in addition to the [first question with working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62951695/embedded-entity-reading-from-originaly-stored-as-blob/62956219#62956219)

I was not able to deserialize the following

```
private @Serialize List<ProduktSprache> produktsprachen;
```

the new class looks like this stored as Blob with orginaly having two fields defined as Text:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Serialize;

public class ProduktSprache implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String sprache;
    private String name;
    private String details;
    private String detailsText; // TEXT
    private String detailsTextHTML; // TEXT
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ... ProduktSprache can not be deserialized (from the Blob). This is again a problem of the original Datastore Handling.

Comment: The field was saved as:
 @Persistent(serialized = "true", defaultFetchGroup = "true")
 private List<ProduktSprache> produktsprachen;
Today the Error logged is: com.googlecode.objectify.impl.EntityMetadata.load> Error loading !1:Produkt(5646485207121920): At path 'produktsprachen': Unable to deserialize <Blob: 489 bytes>

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell what's going on here, but it sounds like you have some data that was serialized (with java serialization) into the field. To figure this out, I'd try to simplify it as much as possible.

Serialized data is written as type `Blob` in the entity. So the first step is to change your `produktsprachen` field to type `Blob`. Now you can load the entity and you have a `byte[]` of data to work with.

Next, try to decode that `byte[]`. Use an `ObjectInputStream` to read the contents and inspect what you actually have present. Whatever structure you find there is what you eventually need to use as your `@Serialized` field type in your Objectify entity class.

Comment: So i gave up and migrated all fields to JSON. That was easy.